# Where does the postgresql parser put the table name?

Tags: c, postgresql, parsing

The source code has "exec_simple_query". After parsing where can the table name be found ?

Comment: What makes you think there *is* a table name?  Suppose the query is `BEGIN TRANSACTION` or a `SELECT` with a `JOIN`.  What then?

Answer (score 0):

The table name is discarded in the parse phase. The parsetree just contains the oid of the table from a relcache lookup, stored in a targetlist entry. Dump the parsetree with `debug_print_plans` to see what I mean.